# I´m trying to apload package allEffects but it gives me a warning message

Tags: runtime-error, warnings

I don´t know with package i should download

```
install.packages("allEffects")

WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/aidav/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘allEffects’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

I tried this:

```
install.packages("allEffects", force = TRUE)
```

And this also:

```
install.packages("pkgload")  # Para actualizar el paquete pkgload
library(pkgload)
devtools::install_github("cran/allEffects")
```